# API GET request with body text/data

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-400

I need to request the API created by another person for this project. In his documentation I have to do the following:

Send GET request to this API URL
https://visblueiotfunctionapptest.azurewebsites.net/api/GetDeviceList

Along with authorization token which I do have and request body

```
{
"UserEmail" : "xxxx@xxxxx.dk", //this can be null

"FromDateUTC" : "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"

}
```

In the postman, this works like a charm and I can get data as I would like to. Problem is when I try to do the same thing from front-end (react-app) or anywhere else (any other API environment like Postman)

I always get 400 bad request which leads me to think there is a problem with data I pass in the body.

I tried to use different ways of sending a request (AXIOS, Fetch, XML, Ajax) the same for all of them. I even tried to generate snippet from Postman and nothing.

Here is the example of my request code

```
var data = "{\"Usermail\":\"cc@ccc.dk\",\"FromDateUTC\":\"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z\"}";

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.withCredentials = true;
      
      xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          console.log(this.responseText);
        }
      });
      
      xhr.open("GET", "http://visblueiotfunctionapptest.azurewebsites.net/api/GetDeviceList");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik4tbEMwbi05REFMcXdodUhZbkhRNjNHZUNYYyIsImtpZCI6Ik4tbEMwbi05REFMcXdodUhZbkhRNjNHZUNYYyJ9.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.bVr93rd8BtooqH9n7Fv9oMu083TNxto-6ArrDap87QljBb7OU1sQ_LHbLxcKle4MXjUc6102yBs_EKTaNN-ojmz7eZ5-JcDiTlgW2VQ_yUDdnScXzwFoCwID5FdmzLHfGPtSncLo0sYwx1AwQi18G0eITMR3y2xdSggd2vX4DCthc_iG8TGLpwr73mFpaIrWoiC-4Z9dTgA9uqN45L-20PcEDymgcdT87b92t6H5c33oc4RXClnNef0x3OV2PMCXBzfPHXGFKpY9rfgJI2gt57b-Ubbh21OQilvg05lKAXeMdi4D1ChFzXyMTqXEYxm4apRQa3phd_Wy2rkgqb4_tA");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "ffe68215-e89d-4847-8f12-deef46d44393");
      
      xhr.send(data);
```

What am I doing wrong here and what is the difference between my request and how Postman does it?

**EDIT**

Why this example works in Postman[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send a request body when using a GET request. Also set the content-type to `application/json`

Try a POST request:

```
var data = {
    "UserEmail": "xxxx@xxxxx.dk",
    "FromDateUTC": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
}
var url = "http://visblueiotfunctionapptest.azurewebsites.net/api/GetDeviceList";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.open("POST", url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer *your secret token*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**EDIT**

If it has to be a GET request you can send the data in the query string:

```
var query_string = "UserEmail=" + encodeURIComponent("xxxx@xxxxx.dk") + "&FromDateUTC=" + encodeURIComponent("2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z")
var url = "http://visblueiotfunctionapptest.azurewebsites.net/api/GetDeviceList";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.open("GET", url + "?" + query_string);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer *your secret token*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});
xhr.send();
```

**EDIT2**

It appears that it is *valid* to send a request body with the GET method. Doing so is discouraged though. See this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/10928331) answer for details.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) The XMLHttpRequest API simply ignores any body when the method is `GET` or `HEAD`.

Your postman seems to include the request body with the `GET` method and the call succeeds.

You are stuck with two possibilities:

- either the API already accepts another format - `GET` with query string or `POST` with request body.
- or you need to convince the maintainer of the API change the implementation.

When the API **only** accepts `GET` and body payload you will **not** be able to use this API using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: This gives me the same error. I know this example might be hard to solve from other people view. 

What I am not sure is why this works fine with GET request and body data in Postman when a lot of people point out GET request shouldn`t have a body data. And another point is if I should use POST when I want to GET data from API that follow up parameters I want to forward with the request. (the API seems to be made that accepts only GET requests)

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking should be in URL string, I tried this but it gives me the same error <Bad request>. Most of all is bugging me why this example works in Postman...? See edit in my post...

Comment: @TomášTomHaverla I updated my answer with new information

Comment: I was away for a week, that is why no answer from me. You are correct and your comments helped me solve the issue.